# Is there an alternative way to sync

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, thread-synchronization

Is there an alternative way to be sure that the threads are ready to recieve the broadcast signal. I want to replace the Sleep(1) function in main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM 4


using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_t tid[NUM];


void *threads(void *arg){
    int tid = (int)arg;
    while(true){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
        //do some work
        cout<<"Thread: "<<tid<<endl;;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

int main(){

    for(int i=0;i<NUM;i++){
        pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,threads,(void*)i);
    }

    Sleep(1);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);

    Sleep(1);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);

    Sleep(1);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried memory barriers before pthread_cond_wait and i thought of using an counter, but nothing worked for me yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condition variables are usually connected to a predicate. In the other threads, check if predicate is already fulfilled (check while holding the mutex protecting the predicate), if so, do not wait on the condition variable. In main, acquire mutex, change predicate while holding the mutex. Then release mutex and signal or broadcast on the condvar. Here is a similar question:
[Synchronisation before pthread_cond_broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721769/synchronisation-before-pthread-cond-broadcast/42764001#42764001)

Here is some example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <cassert>

#define NUM 4
#define SIZE 256


using std::cout;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_t tid[NUM];

int work_available;

void *threads(void *arg)
{
    int tid = *((int*)arg);
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while (work_available == 0) {
            // While loop since cond_wait can have spurious wakeups.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
            cout << "Worker " << tid << " woke up...\n";
            cout << "Work available: " << work_available << '\n';
        }
        if (work_available == -1) {
            cout << "Worker " << tid << " quitting\n";
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); // Easy to forget, better to use C++11 RAII mutexes.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            break;
        }
        assert(work_available > 0);
        work_available--;
        cout << "Worker " << tid << " took one item of work\n";
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        //do some work                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        sleep(2); // simulated work                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        cout << "Worker " << tid << " done with one item of work.\n";
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}


int main()
{
    work_available = 0;

    int args[NUM];
    for (int i=0; i<NUM; i++) {
        args[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, threads, (void*)&args[i]);
    }

    const int MAX_TIME = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TIME; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        work_available++;
        cout << "Main thread, work available: " << work_available << '\n';
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
        sleep(1);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    cout << "Main signalling threads to quit\n";
    work_available = -1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What am I missing? I added the changed code in the first posting

Comment: @TomNeumeier The worker threads should go to sleep only if predicate is *false*. You do not need to toggle predicate several times, only set it to true when it is ok for the threads to proceed beyond the condvar wait.

Comment: @TomNeumeier Of course it works, just depends on what you want to do. I added one example to my answer, you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Your example works for one time invoking the threads from the main thread. I want to be able to signal the threads several times from the main thread.

Comment: @TomNeumeier Yes, I understand. You may use a 'work counter', incrementing it in main thread and decrementing it in workers, signalling in between. Or use a sempahore, but those are not as well integrated with condvars as are mutexes.

Comment: Any further ideas? @Erik Alapää Thank you very much

Comment: @TomNeumeier I added a more elaborate producer-consumer example in my answer now.

Comment: The example you posted works and is perfectly fine, except for one thing, after every run you call sleep(1)  and if you would call the threads hundred thousand times or so (and this is what I want to do) it would take too long.

Comment: @TomNeumeier The sleep is only to simulate work or production in main.

Comment: I do not mean the sleep you use to simulate the work, I mean the sleep after you call pthread_cond_broadcast in the main thread, if you leave it out, it doesn t work anymore.

Comment: @TomNeumeier The sleep in main simulates main doing work to produce work items. Without it, main will finish with the loop too quickly, and then set the variable to -1, signalling the worker threads to quit.

Comment: Assume that the producer is that fast

Comment: @TomNeumeier You can add a way for main to find out when all work has been done by the workers, only then does main signal the workers to exit. Left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: How would you do that. Because even when I know when the workers have done their work, I do not know if they are waiting on the condition yet. I do not want any signal to be lost.

Comment: The reason why any signal can not be lost, is that the worker have to start to work as soon as the signal comes in and shall be finished before the next signal comes